# classic asp to asp.net conversion

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic

hi i am working on project jigsaw puzzle game . i have done with coding in classic asp using vb script and it working properly . i want to do same coding asp.net using vb.net but css style i was written it was not working properly in asp.net can anybody  help me doing this conversion.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setText(pieceID)
{
if (document.getElementById("first").value == '' )
    {
    document.getElementById("first").value=pieceID;
   }
else
    {
    document.getElementById("second").value=pieceID;
    document.swap.submit();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%

dim img
img = "img1.jpg"
%>
<div class="classname"> <img src="<%response.write img%>"> </div> 
<%dim imgPIX
imgPIX = 60 
%>
<style>
.icons { display: block; width: <%response.write imgPIX%>px; height:    <%response.write      imgPIX%>px; background-image: url(<%response.write img%>);    background-repeat: no-repeat; }
<%
dim proper

dim ico_number,col
dim row_number,rw

for row_number = 1 to 6
rw = (row_number - 1) * (-1 * imgPIX) 
    for ico_number = 1 to 6
        col = (ico_number - 1) *(-1 * imgPIX)
 response.write ".icon"& row_number &"_"& ico_number &" { background-position: col    &"px "& rw &"px; } "
        if not proper = "" then
            proper = proper & "," & row_number &"_"& ico_number
        else
            proper = row_number &"_"& ico_number
        end if
        response.write ".icon"& row_number &"_"& ico_number &" { background-position: 0px 0px; } "
    next
next 

%>
</style>


    <%

    dim userfeed
    if request.form("userform") = "" then
        userfeed = random_sort(proper)
    end if

     if request.form("first") <> "" and request.form("second") <> "" then
        userfeed = request.form("userform")
        userfeed = replace(userfeed,request.form("first"),"temp1")
        userfeed = replace(userfeed,request.form("second"),"temp2")

        userfeed = replace(userfeed,"temp1",request.form("second"))
        userfeed = replace(userfeed,"temp2",request.form("first"))

    end if
    %>


    <center>
    <form name="swap" action="default.asp" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="first" ID="first">
    <input type="hidden" name="second" ID="second">
    <input type="hidden" name="userform" ID="userform" value="<%response.write userfeed%>">
    </form>

   <table border="0">
   <%

   if userfeed = proper then
    %>
    <H1>Solved !!</h1>
    <%
    end if
    dim icoarr
    icoarr = split(userfeed,",")
    dim ctr
    ctr =0
    for each piece in icoarr
        if ctr =6 then
            response.write "<tr>"
        end if
    %>
    <td><span class="icons icon<%response.write piece%>" style="float:left;"    onclick="setText('<%response.write piece%>')"></span></td>
    <%

    if ctr =6 then
        ctr =1
    else
        ctr = ctr + 1
    end if
    next
    %>

    <%public function random_sort(arrySTR)
    arrySTR = arrySTR & ","

    dim retstr
    do while arrySTR <> ""
        dim arr 
        arr = split(arrySTR,",")

        dim random_number
        randomize
        random_number=int(rnd*(ubound(arr)-1))+0
        'response.write random_number
         retstr =arr(random_number) & "," & retstr
            arrySTR = replace(arrySTR,arr(random_number) & ",","")
    loop
    retstr = mid(retstr,1,len(retstr)-1)
    'response.write  "<br>" & retstr

    random_sort=retstr

    end function

    %>

    </table>
    </body>
```

Comment: Good luck... Classic ASP and ASP.Net are two different things (completely). You should learn from your experience with building it in ASP, make it better and rewrite it in .Net

Comment: There is a lot to learn with ASP.NET. One is how it separates your code from your HTML into code-behind files. Bear in mind that if you end up with lots of VB code in your .aspx files, you are on the wrong track.

Comment: Do you get any error ? or just the style not applied to ? I think something have to do with the declare of the style. Can we see that page online to see what is not render correctly ?

Comment: what exactly isn't working right?  can you give screenshot of what it should look like or something.  What you have above looks like classic asp which I thought you were putting it into asp.net?

Comment: Technically speaking, VB.NET should have some backward compatibility. Start by posting what error you get and on what line of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Asp.Net WEBMATRIX tool for converting the same code to Asp.Net with minimal effort

http://www.asp.net/web-pages

Comment: no i am not getting error but css style sheet not working because the line where i am  displaying the divide images. it was just running that loop only